# Examples of usage of JSF

Tags: java, jsf, web

Are their any good websites (characterized by high usage), that use JSF for their back-end? I have just started working with the basics of the framework. If I see some websites using JSF, may be I will be able to better appreciate the use of the technology.

Also could you mention the benefits of using JSF validation viz a viz the browser side validation of content using JavaScript.

Comment: I believe the first part of your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514/public-popular-websites-using-javaserver-faces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/RealWorldJSFLinks) for a list of JSF sites.

In addition see the references for two famous JSF component frameworks:

- [Richfaces](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesInProduction)
- [Icefaces](http://www.icefaces.org/main/ajax-java/whoicefaces.iface)

As for the validation - it better be on both sides - on the client side (javascript) for better usability, and on the server side for better security.

Comment: i see very few common names there... It seems some pages of apple.com use jsf.

Comment: what do you mean by "common names" ?

Comment: I am sorry. I meant famous names (like so which i understand is built on asp.net mvc).
there's page by apple.com and other websites serving small communities.  Some famous websites are there. but when i visit those sites, the url does not contain "faces". i believe that typically all facelets will reside in the faces directory. why does the url not contain the word faces?

Comment: this is configurable. You can have pretty urls with JSF (with prettyfaces), so the url tells you nothing about the technology.

Answer (score 3):

ebay, volvo, bmw, costco, TNT, Lufthanza and thousands of more websites use JSF for complete or parts of their websites in production.

Check your answer at http://www.primefaces.org/whouses. (Who uses primefaces.) Primefaces is JQuery based UI component library for JSF and is one of the most popular UI Libraries in JSF.
Whoever runs Primefaces , runs on JSF.

You can also check presentation on ebay supplier portal about how ebay uses JSF to achieve scalability and performance. Search on youtube for "eBay, Connecting Buyers and Sellers Globally via JavaServer Faces" (Oct 2014)

The presentation in PDF format is here: https://oracleus.activeevents.com/2014/connect/fileDownload/session/DB08F809615ABF16F149FEC02B892C10/CON2892_Paulsen-J1eBaySelling.pdf

Answer (score 1):

On the validation questions:

**Server side Advantages:**

- Most common validation rules can be declaratively specified i.e. validation rules are specified in tag attributes. Since there is very little code written, this is highly maintainable
- For the rest of the validation rules, one can write custom Validator implementations. These implementations (unlike custom components) are straight forward. Although they are more work than declarative validation, but still more maintainable than the JavaScript approach.

**Server side Dis-advantages:**

- Usability is the biggest issue here. Any validation failures can be reported only when the complete HTML form is submitted (not when the value is keyed in). In JSF 2.0 this downside can be overcome by making ajax calls to your validation logic and reporting failures as values are keyed in

**JavaScript Advantages**

- Usability - as detailed above - can report failures as values are keyed in

**JavaScript Disadvantages**

- Even with JS libraries like jQuery, it can be pretty difficult to implement and maintain js code that supports all browsers. Adding support to a new browser can be very expensive.
- All data required to complete validation must be pre-loaded when the response is rendered. Whereas in the server side approach the validation code can lookup any data it needs.

Comment: The 'server side Dis-advantages' (well, the one...) is not valid anymore with ajax and client-side validation enhancements in e.g. PrimeFaces. The 'javascript disadvantages' as well with modern ui frameworks on top of jquery or not